# finding path to all 3 corners on a chess board starting from 0,0 isn't working

Tags: arrays, c, chess, knights-tour

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIDE 8

#define VISITED 1
#define NOT_VISITED 0

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE

void printBoard(int board[][SIDE]);
int goHorsie(int board[][SIDE], int x, int y, int step);

int main(void)
{

    int board[SIDE][SIDE] = { NOT_VISITED };

    goHorsie(board, 0, 0, 1);

    printBoard(board);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int goHorsie(int board[][SIDE], int x, int y, int step)
{
    int res = FALSE;
    int cor1 = 0, cor2 = 0, cor3 = 0;
    if (x == 7 && y == 7)
    {
        cor1 = 1;
    }
    if (x == 7 && y == 0)
    {
        cor2 = 1;
    }
    if (x == 0 && y == 7)
    {
        cor3 = 1;
    }
    if (cor1 == 1 && cor2 == 1 && cor3 == 1)
    {
        printf("FOUND ALL!\n");
        res = TRUE;
    }
    else if (board[x][y] != NOT_VISITED //We were here already!
        || x >= SIDE || y >= SIDE || x < 0 || y < 0)
    {
        res = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        board[x][y] = step;
        step++;
        res = 
            goHorsie(board, x + 1, y - 2, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x + 2, y + 1, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x + 2, y - 1, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x + 1, y + 2, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x - 2, y + 1, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x - 2, y - 1, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x - 1, y + 2, step) ||
            goHorsie(board, x + 1, y - 2, step);
            
        if (!res)
        {
            board[x][y] = NOT_VISITED;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

/*
Prints the chess board
*/
void printBoard(int board[][SIDE])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIDE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIDE; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

im using recursion to find the path to all 3 corners.

i ran the program for about 20min now and it's still didn't get to the solution.

ik why its taking too long but not sure if it will even get me to the answer.

so my question is did i make the function right and will it eventually give me the right answer (the path to all 3 corners).

Comment: don't show us your entire code unless it has an interest. please be more precise in your question. What are you failing at precisely. Please update your title and show us the code part failing

Comment: I'm not sure if your recursive function has any base cases.

Comment: If your program is running that long, it's clearly a case of infinite recursion. Unless I am mistaken, you also don't handle the case where your Knight leaves the board, either in positive or negative direction.

Comment: im asking about the function "goHorsie" if i made it right because it's taking too long to get to the answer still running it for 30min and hasn't got an answer so my question is did i make the recursion right to get to the answer which is the path to all 3 corners starting from 0,0

Comment: I think your base case is wrong. How can `cor1`, `cor2`, and `cor3` each equal 1? `x` has to be simultaneously 0 and 7, and so does `y`.

Comment: hmm how do u suggest solving that i think i get what u mean

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't know what your code is trying to do. I don't really know what you mean by a path to all 3 corners - would you like this path printing? Storing? I would start by fixing your base cases - ensuring that you have a terminating condition to your recursion.

A good first step would be ensuring that `x` and `y` are in the range of your board.

Comment: i did do that at line 68
also what i mean by corners is the path to get to the top right, bottom right and bottom left that's what i mean by all corners

Comment: so anyone could help me?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int i = 0, j = 0;`  these two variables are being shadowed by the two variables declared in the `for()` statements

Comment: strongly suggest, at the beginning of the `gohorse()` function to print a line that contains the current values of `x`, `y` and `step`